# How to finish a 2 player turn-based game in Google-play-services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

This is my finishTurnBasedGame() function which I am running when the 2nd player has played his turn.

```
public void finishTurnBasedGame(TurnBasedMatch mMatch){
        
        showSpinner();
        Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(mHelper.getApiClient(), mMatch.getMatchId())
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                        processResult(result);
                    }
                });
        isTurnBasedGameComplete = false;
        isDoingTurn = false;
        setViewVisibility();
}
```

And this is the error I am getting from Logcats. The doesn't get finished and turn shift back to 1st player.

> E/TurnBasedAgent﹕ Failed to finish match: null
>
> W/TurnBasedAgent﹕{"code":409,"errors":[{"message":"Invalid operation for player 106811846324577577566. Reason: First call to Finish must be by pending player.","domain":"global","reason":"InvalidParticipantState"}]}

Don't know what is the correct way to do this but essentially what I want is once the 2nd player plays his turn the game should end with the result. I don't want the turn to go back to 1st player again when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

1. When you call takeTurn for player 2, specify player 2 as next participant. That way player 2 will still have turn, and you can then call finishMatch.
2. Don't call takeTurn for player 2. Instead call the finishMatch method that includes match data and participant results:

   ```
   finishMatch(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String matchId, byte[] matchData, List<ParticipantResult> results).
   ```

   This will update the match data on both players devices and finish the match.